# How to change image by clicking on event?

Tags: javascript, function

I tried but it's not working. When I click on `.imgChangeBtn`  element, this element’s `src` value will be puss on the `#imgDisplay` element. 
**Note** `imgPath` variable is not getting any value. And Anonymous function is not set on this element. I don't know why!

```
<img id="imgDisplay" src="default.jpg"/>
<ul>
    <li><img class="imgChangeBtn" src="wolverine.jpg"></li>
    <li><img class="imgChangeBtn" src="Iron_man.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<script>
    var DisplayBoard = document.querySelector("#imgDisplay");
    var ChangeBtn = document.querySelector(".imgChangeBtn");

    ChangeBtn.click(function () {
         var imgPath = document.querySelector('.imgChangeBtn').getAttribute('src');
         DisplayBoard.src = imgPath;

         console.log(imgPath);
   })
</script>
```

Comment: [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) isn't the same as [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop through all the elements with the class `imgChangeBtn` using `querySelectorAll` then attach the click listener using `addEventListener` in every iteration, check the snippet below.

```js
var displayBoard = document.querySelector("#imgDisplay");
var changeBtnList = document.querySelectorAll(".imgChangeBtn");

for (var i = 0; i < changeBtnList.length; i++) {
  changeBtnList[i].addEventListener('click', changeSrc);
}


function changeSrc() {
  var imgPath = this.getAttribute('src');

  displayBoard.src = imgPath;

  console.log(displayBoard.src);
}
```

```html
<img id="imgDisplay" src="default.jpg" />

<ul>
  <li><img class="imgChangeBtn" src="wolverine.jpg" alt="wolverine.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img class="imgChangeBtn" src="Iron_man.jpg" alt="Iron_man.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector('.imgChangeBtn').setAttribute("src", imgPath);` in order to set src.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like below. You can also reference 'this' within the function, to make your code shorter.

```
var DisplayBoard = document.querySelector("#imgDisplay");
var ChangeBtn = document.querySelector(".imgChangeBtn");

ChangeBtn.onclick = function () {
   var imgPath = this.getAttribute('src');
   DisplayBoard.src = imgPath;
   console.log(imgPath);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I write this script in pure javascript not jquery

Comment: No problem - accept the answer if it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I created you a codepen for what I think you are trying to achieve, requires jQuery: https://codepen.io/MayhemBliz/pen/eerzdJ

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
  var selectedImgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
  console.log(selectedImgSrc);
  $("#img").attr("src",selectedImgSrc);
});
```

```css
#img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xnscj78AnbBm/giphy.gif"/>
<ul>
    <li><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/dWOhtHvkWgRq0/giphy.gif"></li>
    <li><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xnscj78AnbBm/giphy.gif"></li>
</ul>
```